# How to dynamically specify the path to the class library DLL?

Tags: c#, class, dynamic, dll, load

Target: dynamically set the path to the class library c#.
For example, if the path to the DLL is not found.
Find DLL manually and specify the path where to load.

Comment: You can use a FileDialog to find the dll and reflection to load classed from the dll

Comment: @SonerGönül

I still did nothing.
I wrote a class library and reference it in the project.
Everything works.
As long as the DLL is in the right place.

Therefore, I ask the question of how to specify the path to the application specific DLL if it is not found on runtime.

Comment: You should click the checkmark on answers you've received that answer your question. I notice you haven't done this for any of the 20 or so questions you've asked and had answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a path to the app config that is searched for DLLs. Here's an example:

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="C:\myDLLDirectory\" />
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

See here for more information and ideas. There are several ways to do it: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/837908